# Cannot fix my pagination, the same comments are displayed 2-3 times

Tags: php

can anyone help me please? I'm stucking...  I need to build a comment section with pagination but I have the problem, the same comments are displayed 2 or 3 times and my pagination is not working, it doesn't change the page, I cannot find the error :(
I'll be very grateful if someone help me :)

Thank you

```js
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
require_once ("pagination.class.php");
$perPage = new PerPage();
$sql = "SELECT * from comments";
$paginationlink = "getresult.php?page=";
$page = 1;
if (! empty($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
}
$start = ($page - 1) * $perPage->perpage;
if ($start < 0) {
    $start = 0;
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$perpageresult = $perPage->perpage($result->num_rows, $paginationlink);
$query = $sql . " limit " . $start . "," . $perPage->perpage;
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$output = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // $output .= '<div class="question"><input type="hidden" id="rowcount" name="rowcount" value="' . $result->num_rows . '" />' . $row["question"] . '</div>';
    // $output .= '<div class="answer">' . $row["answer"] . '</div>';


    $output .= ' <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Par <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
   <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;"class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
    
    
    </div>';

    $output .= get_reply_comment($connection, $row["comment_id"]);
    
}

echo $output;

function get_reply_comment($connection, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0) {

    $sql = "SELECT * from comments WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'";

    $output = '';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    // $count = $statement->rowCount();
    //  $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    

 if($parent_id == 0)
 {
  $marginleft = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
 }

//  if($count > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


        $output .= '

         <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:'.$marginleft.'px">
   <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
   <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
    <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
</div>
        
        
        ';

        $output .= get_reply_comment($connection, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);


    // }

//  }
 }
 return $output;

};




if (! empty($perpageresult)) {
    $output .= '<div id="pagelink">' . $perpageresult . '</div>';
}
print $output;
?>

<?php

class PerPage
{

    public $perpage;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->perpage = 5;
    }

    function perpage($count, $href)
    {
        $output = '';
        if (! isset($_GET["page"]))
            $_GET["page"] = 1;
        if ($this->perpage != 0)
            $pages = ceil($count / $this->perpage);
        if ($pages > 1) {
            if ($_GET["page"] == 1)
                $output = $output . '<span class="disabled"><<</span><span class="disabled"><</span>';
            else
                $output = $output . '<a class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . (1) . '\')" ><<</a><a class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . ($_GET["page"] - 1) . '\')" ><</a>';

            if (($_GET["page"] - 3) > 0) {
                if ($_GET["page"] == 1)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=1 class="current">1</span>';
                else
                    $output = $output . '<a class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . '1\')" >1</a>';
            }
            if (($_GET["page"] - 3) > 1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }

            for ($i = ($_GET["page"] - 2); $i <= ($_GET["page"] + 2); $i ++) {
                if ($i < 1)
                    continue;
                if ($i > $pages)
                    break;
                if ($_GET["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . $i . ' class="current">' . $i . '</span>';
                else
                    $output = $output . '<a class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . $i . '\')" >' . $i . '</a>';
            }

            if (($pages - ($_GET["page"] + 2)) > 1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }
            if (($pages - ($_GET["page"] + 2)) > 0) {
                if ($_GET["page"] == $pages)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . ($pages) . ' class="current">' . ($pages) . '</span>';
                else
                    $output = $output . '<a class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . ($pages) . '\')" >' . ($pages) . '</a>';
            }

            if ($_GET["page"] < $pages)
                $output = $output . '<a  class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . ($_GET["page"] + 1) . '\')" >></a><a  class="link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . ($pages) . '\')" >>></a>';

            else
                $output = $output . '<span class="disabled">></span><span class="disabled">>></span>';
            $output = $output . '<span id="loader-icon">
                <img src="img/LoaderIcon.gif" />
                </span>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<section class="comments-section" id="comments">

  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="h2 left">Lorem ipsum</h2>



    <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom ou pseudo" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea style="resize: none;" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Redigez votre commentaire" maxlength="1000" rows="6"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publier" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <span id="comment_message"></span>
    <br />



    <div id="display_comment"></div>



    <!-- <button class="loadmore" id="more">Load More</button> -->
    <script>
      function getresult(url) {
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            rowcount: $("#rowcount").val()
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#pagination").html(data);
            $("#loader-icon").hide();
          },
          error: function() {}
        });
      }
    </script>

    <div id="pagination">
      <input type="hidden" name="rowcount" id="rowcount" />
    </div>
    <script>
      getresult("PHP/getresult.php");
    </script>


</section>
```

Comment: You might want to slim down your code to only what's necessary to answer the question.  What have you done to debug?

Comment: Hello, but I think that all is important to understand the problem. The comments are fetched from DB but they are repeated and when i click on my pagination to change the page it doesn't work...

Comment: Not even context for us to assist with. You are using prepared statements incorrectly as well. Parameterize the values. Debug what `get_reply_comment` does, verify comments coming from that are correct. Need to identify where the duplication occurs first.

Comment: @StefanSaulic there's a lot to go through here, you need to debug further.  If you don't know if the issue is with your pagination links on the frontend or the pagination logic on the backend, you have not done enough debugging.

Comment: You're selecting all the comments, then if the comment has children, you get those as well. The first query never checks to see if it's a parent or child, so you're getting the child comments twice.

Comment: This likely modifies something and I can't see what it is but it's likely causing a problem: `$perpageresult = $perPage->perpage($result->num_rows, $paginationlink);`

Comment: As for the pagination, what part of it isn't working? The clicking, the URL generation, or what happens when you actually click on the link and it loads the new page? If it does, since you don't show the definition for `getresult()`

Comment: @user3783243 I don't know backend, i'm front, I just need to resolve this problem because i'm working on a project alone and i have no person to help me. I'm stucking on it longtime

Comment: @StefanSaulic Can you show us the PerPage class definition?

Comment: @JoePhillips  You can check my code here https://codecollab.io/@stefke1210/comments Thank you very much